# What is the meaning of "scare something apart?"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I would like to ask about the meaning of the phrase "scare [something] apart."
I have searched but I couldn't find any result.

This is the context:

> As to the prevalence of the crisis, Sheehy is noncommittal,
> though she writes in general terms and clearly
> expects her readers to identify with her interview subjects.
> Others have been less reserved. In the preface to a
> neglected classic of midlife mythology, Barbara Fried’s
> *The Middle-Age Crisis*, published in 1967, psychology professor
> Morris Stein wrote that the "crisis is ubiquitous":
> "Each of us goes through it in his own way, experiences
> it with greater or lesser intensity, and emerges
> from it more or less reconciled to the years ahead. It is a 'natural' developmental crisis, and it is
> unavoidable."
>
> **Scare quotes apart**, the picture is one of social or biological
> fate. We are programmed for the midlife crisis, men
> and women alike, and the question is not whether but
> when. We had better be prepared.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase is **[noun] apart**, meaning "ignoring [noun]" or "despite [noun]." From wiktionary, [**apart**, adverb,](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apart#Adverb) sense 3: *Aside; away; not included.*

In the case the noun is [**scare quotes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes): quotation marks used by the author to indicate that they have some problem with the term used within the quotes.

The author of the passage quotes Stein, who wrote:

> It is a "natural" developmental crisis, and it is unavoidable.

Stein used scare quotes around the word *natural*, perhaps indicating that he didn't think that was the proper way of describing the crisis but acknowledging that others did use it. Or maybe he was afraid of being accused of not being formal enough; writers sometimes use scare quotes to introduce a colloquialism or industrial term of art that is not part of standard academic English.

The author mentions Stein's use of scare quotes and discards it. They are saying that they think the word *natural* is a perfectly fine descriptor—the process is "one of social or biological fate" and therefore quite natural, so they think the scare quotes were unnecessary.

Comment: I have added the quote

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought it was a phrasal verb! so the scare quote is the word "natural" right?

Comment: @Lili, yes, "natural" is the word that has been scare-quoted. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank a lot! Your answer was really helpful.